# Can we use float32 type data calculation to simulate noise in float64 data?

Tags: python, noise

I'm running a dynmaic computer simulation in complex number with double precision, i.e. numpy.complex128. However, there came a time when I need to consider to put the noise into the iteration, which would significantly reduce the iteration speed.

However, then I realized a complication before: in order to achieve the accuracy of the iteration, the simulation was using double precision and thus pretended to keep  all the useful information. In the case of introducing noise, essentially what happened was that, one want to introduce uncertainty into the iteration matrix. Since the matrix is big(much over 30 by 30), we can consider the variation in "small digits" in float32 effectively to be the uniform random noise in float64.

Thus, to achieve the noise-affected simulation, one may simply reduce the precision from float64 to float32.(although the degree of influence could not be clearly controlled in this case)

Could it be possible for the above analysis? and can we use float32 as a noise influenced simulation in float64 simulation?

Comment: Using float32 merely truncates the data, making it more discrete. It's still accurate though, so I doubt this works as noise.  Whether or not it works as noise depends entirely on your simulation, nobody else can answer that for you.

Comment: @MooingDuck Exactly (because of the truncation), so in the view of float64, the leading number start at 9th decimal ( the most influential digits in the "non float32") was missing. In the case of matrix iteration, especially in the case which involved matrix multiplication, this number, which became a standard uniform distribution in the case of matrix larger than 30 by 30, played the most influential part to the difference between float64 simulation (after truncation) and the float 32 simulation.